# Covariance and indicator function relations

Tags: probability, covariance, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ be  two (sub) sigma-algebras of some probability space. [Rio (2017), pp. 4](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783662543221) defines the coefficient:

$$\alpha(\mathcal A,\mathcal B)=2\sup\{\lvert Cov(1_A,1_B):(A,B)\in\mathcal A\times \mathcal B\rvert\}, \quad (a)$$
where the function $1_W(x)$ stands for the indicator function given a measurable set $W$.
After some paragraphs, he states that "clearly",
$$\alpha(\mathcal A,\mathcal B)=\sup\{\lvert Cov(1_A-1_{A^c},1_B):(A,B)\in\mathcal A\times \mathcal B\rvert\},\quad (1)$$
and
$$Cov(1_A-1_{A^c},1_B)=E((P(B\lvert \mathcal A)-P(B))(1_A-1_{A^c})).\quad (2)$$

I cannot get the relation between $(a)$ and $(1)$ and cannot see the equality $(2)$. Can someone help me to clarify these points?

Comment: Covariance is bilinear and $Cov(1_A+1_{A^c},1_B) = 0$ 

so $Cov(1_{A^c},1_B) = -Cov(1_A,1_B)$ and $Cov(1_A-1_{A^c},1_B) = 2Cov(1_A,1_B)$

Comment: @Henry can you explain why the first covariance is zero?

Comment: $1_A+1_{A^c} =1$ and $1$ does not vary

Comment: Hum. $Cov(1_{A\cup A^c},1_B)=P(B)-P(B)=0$. Nice